# Bug with pipeline

Tags: reactjs, typescript, cicd, msw

I have some problem with my CI CD.
Some days ago, library "headers-polyfill" was updated, and my new pipelines were failed.
Earlier, before this update, I pushed branch into dev, and it was good.
Now I have good pipeline in dev, and if I create empty branch from dev, and push it in gitlab - pipelines fail with errors.
Also I have msw library in project and error appears when build tries to collect helpers for msw.

ERROR in ../node_modules/@mswjs/data/node_modules/msw/node_modules/headers-polyfill/lib/Headers.js 9:25

If you now something like this, help me please, share your ideas.

Comment: We don't know what CI/CD you are using and how your config file looks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, upgrading msw to latest - solves this issue:
https://github.com/mswjs/msw/releases/tag/v0.47.3

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).